# Tag badge count is only granted after a positive score of 100 votes and not after 100 upvotes

Tags: bug, badges, tag-badges

I just downvoted an answer and found out, that the user now has a -1 score for the asp.net tag on SO.

I don't know if that is by design, but I guess that behaviour is in contradiction to the bronze tag badges, which say that you need +100 upvotes.
If the user would be upvoted 100 times, he'd only have 99 upvotes and did not receive the badge. (Technically he would have 100 upvotes in the asp.net tag. I just checked, the same behaviour affected me. I had 4 downvotes and only got the badge at a count of 100, so technically I had 104 upvotes before receiving the badge)

So I guess either your system does not work as told or the tooltip text is wrong.

This is the user https://stackoverflow.com/users/238546/james-xu

Screenshot of the upvote count:
[image]

Badge description (screenshot is of my profile):
[image]

Comment: I thought this had been changed previously.